Non trivial subspaces of the permutation module $\mathbb{C}[X]$
Let $X={1,2,...,n}$. Consider the vector space $\mathbb{C}[X]=\{c_1\cdot1+\dots+c_n\cdot n : c_i \in \mathbb{C}\}$
Viewing this as an $S_n$ module, we call this the permutation module. I want to decompose this into irreducibles (with respect to action of $S_n$ of course)
I can see that
$$W_1 = \{ c_1\cdot1+\dots+c_n\cdot n : c_1=c_2=\dots=c_n \}$$
and
$$W_2 = \{ c_1\cdot1+\dots+c_n\cdot n : c_1+c_2=\dots+c_n=0 \}$$
are vector spaces closed under action of $S_n$. Why are these the only two non-trivial subspaces closed under $S_n$ action as this paper also claims (page 3, section 1.3) ?
Note: I am starting with rep theory and havent reached indecomposables, maschke's theorem and schur's lemma. I am looking for a solution which can be found using only the basic defintions of irreducibles, representations, invariant spaces, etc.
Also, I have shown that $W_1$ and $W_2$ are irreducible. Does this do the job?

Note that $W_1+W_2=\mathbb{C} [X]$. Consider then how the existence of another irreducible module threatens the irreducibility of $W_2$.

@Tom thats what im not getting. Why should the new irred be a subspace of $W_2$

Suppose $W_3$ is irred. Then $W_3\cap W_1=\emptyset$, otherwise we would have $W_1\subset W_3$ (as $\text{dim}W_1=1$) and $W_3$ could not be irred. $W_1+W_2=\mathbb{C}[X]$ then forces $W_3\subset W_2$.

Also just checking that the early "$=$" in the definition of $W_2$ should be a "$+$"?

thanks @Tom. Also, yes, the = should be a +

I think that you made a mistake here @Tom. If you take for example three line $D_1$, $D_2$ and $D_3$ in the plane, you can still have $D_1 \cap D_2 = D_1 \cap D_3 = D_2 \cap D_3 = {0}$. The argument a bit more subtle. Let $W$ be an irreducible subrepresentation such that $W \cap W_1 = {0}$. Any non zero vector of $W$ then belongs in $\mathbb{C}[X]\setminus W_1$ $($i.e. it has two coordinates that are not equal$)$. Letting $S_n$ acting on $W$, you can permute those two coordinate and subtract this new vector from the first one to obtain a vector of the form $(0, \dots, \lambda, \dots, 0)$.

This new vector is in $W_3$ and therefore $W \cap W_3$ is non trivial, which imply that $W = W_3$ by irreducibility.
